# Can't install the package channels-redis on PyCharm

Tags: installation, pycharm, django-channels

I tried this Tutorial: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_1.html
At some point in the tutorial I am required to install a package called channels_redis but everytime I am trying to install it no matter if it's via the terminal or via the settings I get an error
The errorlog itself is actually too big to post here so I will post only the parts which I think are important or atleast differ from the rest of it:

```
Collecting twisted
  Using cached Twisted-20.3.0.tar.bz2 (3.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from twisted) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from twisted) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from twisted) (17.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from twisted) (20.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from twisted) (20.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyHamcrest!=1.10.0,>=1.9.0 in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from twisted) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from twisted) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->twisted) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.4.2->twisted) (51.1.1)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for twisted, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: twisted
    Running setup.py install for twisted ... |    WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1252
    WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1252
    WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1252
    WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1252
    WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1252
error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\derwilliwonka\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h8ndiq14\\twisted_dc4125a9150843759c06aa40
cb0acf6c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\derwilliwonka\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h8ndiq14\\twisted_dc4125a9150843759c06aa40cb0acf6c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.rea
d().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\derwilliwonka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qqc9cr4l\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-
managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\include\site\python3.9\twisted'
         cwd: C:\Users\derwilliwonka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h8ndiq14\twisted_dc4125a9150843759c06aa40cb0acf6c\
    Complete output (983 lines):
```

At this point there is a huge list and due to limitations of how much I can post I will give you guys the first 10 lines

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
copying src\twisted\copyright.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
copying src\twisted\plugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
copying src\twisted\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
copying src\twisted\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted
```

It's copying and creating quite a lot of files and then this part comes:

```
writing src\Twisted.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\Twisted.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to src\Twisted.egg-info\entry_points.txt
writing requirements to src\Twisted.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to src\Twisted.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.misc' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bugfix' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.doc' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.feature' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.removal' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'NEWS' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'README' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'newsfragments' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\CREDITS'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\ChangeLog.Old'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'pyproject.toml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveralls.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.circleci'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.circleci'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bin'
no previously-included directories found matching 'admin'
no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'docs\historic\2003'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\historic\2003'
writing manifest file 'src\Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
```

Afterwards again 20 lines of copying and creating before this last part:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Id:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\include -IC:\Users\derwilliwonka\
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\derwilliwonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\
10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Rele
ase\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
    raiser.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\ven
v\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\derwilliwonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\derwilliwonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39 /LIBPATH:d:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program
Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x6
4 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64 /EXPORT:PyInit_raiser build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.pyd /I
MPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.lib
       Bibliothek "build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.lib" und Objekt "build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.exp" werden erstellt.
    Code wird generiert.
    Codegenerierung ist abgeschlossen.
    building 'twisted.internet.iocpreactor.iocpsupport' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\internet
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Id:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\include -IC:\Users\derwilliwonka\
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\derwilliwonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\
10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c
 /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.obj
    iocpsupport.c
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2229): warning C4047: "=": Anzahl der Dereferenzierungen bei "__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE" und "HANDLE" unterschiedlich
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: "CreateIoCompletionPort": Zeigertyp f\x81r \x81bergebenen Parameter 1 stimmt nicht mit dem deklarierten Zeigertyp \x81berein
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: "CreateIoCompletionPort": Zeigertyp f\x81r \x81bergebenen Parameter 2 stimmt nicht mit dem deklarierten Zeigertyp \x81berein
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4047: "=": Anzahl der Dereferenzierungen bei "__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE" und "HANDLE" unterschiedlich
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2492): warning C4022: "GetQueuedCompletionStatus": Zeigertyp f\x81r \x81bergebenen Parameter 1 stimmt nicht mit dem deklarierten Zeigertyp \x81berein
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2838): warning C4022: "PostQueuedCompletionStatus": Zeigertyp f\x81r \x81bergebenen Parameter 1 stimmt nicht mit dem deklarierten Zeigertyp \x81berein
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2949): warning C4022: "CloseHandle": Zeigertyp f\x81r \x81bergebenen Parameter 1 stimmt nicht mit dem deklarierten Zeigertyp \x81berein
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(3292): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(4932): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5149): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5786): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6146): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6164): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6182): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6509): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(7614): error C2039: "tp_print" ist kein Member von "_typeobject".
    C:\Users\derwilliwonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: Siehe Deklaration von "_typeobject"
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8421): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8437): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\derwilliwonka\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h8ndiq    C:\Users\derwilliwonka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: Siehe Dek
laration von "_typeobject"
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8421): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length
': deprecated in 3.3
    src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8437): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length
': deprecated in 3.3
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.2
9333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\derwilliwonka\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h8ndiq14\
\twisted_dc4125a9150843759c06aa40cb0acf6c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\derwilliwonka\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h8ndiq14\\twisted_dc4125a9150843759c06aa40cb0acf6c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open
'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\derwilliwonka\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qqc9cr4l\install-record.
txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\coding\pyhton\chatapp\venv\include\site\python3.9\twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am working on Windows 10 with the current Version of PyCharm running on it. All other installed packages including pip are up to date.
The Path Variables of PyCharm and Visual Studio is set.
To be honest I even have big troubles understanding what the error is telling me.
Can anybody explain to me what the problem is? Or maybe some workaround to install channels_redis?

Comment: I recommend using Docker, I tried a lot in Windows to install django-channels and I couldn't. It would be better to use Linux or docker images for it

Comment: Have you installed redis on your system?

Comment: @user70 That's what I will try today as somebody mentioned it on reddit too.

Comment: @AjayLingayat I have to confess no I didnt. I thought redis was a package inside PyCharm/Django and not something I can install seperatly. Yes I am dumb but I learn^^

Thanks for the answers folks. I try it out and comment later if it worked

Answer (score 1):

The way I resolved the issue was 
1)download the twisted file from 
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted
version no: Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl 
2)then open your virtual environment in the command prompt
type the following command

```
pip install file:///C:/Users/<your-username>/Downloads/Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```

3)then install django-channels once again